# SVG. Не могу понять, почему не меняется цвет при наведении

Tags: svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg width="6cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 600 500"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">  
    <desc>11</desc>

    <script > <![CDATA[    

        function circle_click(evt) {     
     var circle = evt.target;     
      var currentRadius = circle.getAttribute("stroke");     
       if (currentRadius == "blue")        circle.setAttribute("stroke", "white");      else        circle.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");    }  

    function circle_over(evt) {      
  var circle1 = evt.target;  
   circle1.setAttribute("fill", "red");   }  

    function circle_out(evt) {   
  var circle2 = evt.target;  
   circle2.setAttribute("fill", "white");   }  


]]>
 </script> 
     <circle onclick="circle_click(evt)" mouseover="circle_over(evt)" mouselive="circle_out(evt)" cx="300" cy="225" r="100"    stroke="blue"      fill="red"/> 
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Индентируйте, пожалуйста, код!  У вас неверно названы обработчики
событий.  Должно быть:

```svg
<circle
  onclick="circle_click(evt)"
  onmouseover="circle_over(evt)"
  onmouseout="circle_out(evt)"
  cx="300"
  cy="225"
  r="100"
  stroke="blue"
  fill="red"/>
```